# change form input background color if text present

Tags: css, forms, input, background-color

**MY GOAL:** I want to have three background color states, empty (no text/selection made), focus (entering text/making selection), and not empty (text present/selection made). I have been able to set the color of an empty input and to alter the background if entering text/making a selection. But, once a user goes to the next input, the original background color returns signifying that it is empty vs full.

I've tried various CSS solutions, some javascript but I am not very good at javascript. I've looked through stack for help, googled, played with various solutions, but nothing has worked.

My CSS:
/*  yellow lite     #d3f8d3    lightgreen  */
form input:empty,
form textarea:empty {
background-color: #fff1a6!important;
}

```
/*  light green     #d3f8d3    lightgreen  */
form input,
form textarea {
    background-color: lightpink!important;
    }

form input:focus, 
form textarea:focus {
    background-color: #d3f8d3!important;
    }
```

My Form Input Example:

```
<div class="form-outline   bg_color-white">
    <input type="text"   id="discordIS"   name="discordIS"   value="<?=$discordIS;?>"   class="form-control"   required />
    <label class="form-label" for="discordIS">Discord NAME</label>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: `:empty` is the wrong pseudo class to use for this to begin with, because that's for elements that have no _children_ (which input fields and textareas never do.) You should go look into `:valid`/`:invalid` to handle an empty field in combination with the `required` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to a certain extent for this by introducing a required attribute to your input or textarea elements.

This means you end up with more states: valid/invalid/focus and so can have a 3-way coloring.

Obviously you'll want to play around to decide exactly what combination of states you want (and whether or not the inputs are actually required or whether that is being used just for this coloring).

```css
input:invalid {
  background: pink;
}

input:focus {
  background: cyan;
}

input:valid {
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<input required/>
```